# geom_boxplot is not plotting the IQR from a summarised dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help trying to plot the following structure.
This is a summarised dataset that contains the different time of evaluation "session", the treatment arm "studienarm", and the upper and lower IQR as well as the CI. I am trying to plot the box plot of the different values at the different evaluation.
The problem is that the IQR box is not showing but the other features are fine.

```
mucca_summary_median <- data.frame(
  session = c("baseline_diff", "visit_12mo_diff", "visit_18mo_diff", "baseline_diff", "visit_12mo_diff", "visit_18mo_diff"),
  studienarm = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)),
  count = c(28, 28, 28, 25, 25, 25),
  median_value = c(0.0000000, 0.1477152, 0.2282074, 0.0000000, -0.2257790, 0.4806886),
  lower_q25 = c(0.0000000, -0.9442851, -2.0962150, 0.0000000, -1.0870302, -2.5670724),
  upper_q75 = c(0.000000, 1.931601, 1.415828, 0.000000, 2.028250, 2.474128),
  lower_ci25 = c(0.000000, -8.983193, -8.046044, 0.000000, -12.077256, -15.471589),
  upper_ci975 = c(0.000000, 6.628575, 4.123004, 0.000000, 6.212714, 5.943969)
)

mucca_long <- ggplot(mucca_summary_median, aes(x = session, y = median_value, color = studienarm)) + 
geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.1), aes(ymin = lower_q25, ymax = upper_q75)) + 
geom_line(aes(group = studienarm), position = position_dodge(width = 0.1)) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower_ci25, ymax = upper_ci975), 
                width = 0.25, linewidth = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.1)) + 
labs(x = "Session", y = expression(~Delta~ "MUCCA"/"cm"^2)) +
labs(color = "Treatment arm") +
scale_color_manual(labels = c("High dose", "Low dose"), values = c(1, 2)) + 
geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Baseline", "12 months", "18 months"))
```

Comment: There are two changes that will cause the boxplot quartiles to be drawn. Include stat="identity", and include all 5 boxplot variables in your aes mapping. `ggplot() + geom_boxplot(data=mucca_summary_median, mapping=aes(x = session, color = studienarm, middle = median_value, lower = lower_q25, upper = upper_q75, ymin = lower_ci25, ymax = upper_ci975), stat="identity")`

Comment: You may want to try using `geom_crossbar` and `geom_errorbar` together, in place of `geom_boxplot`.